# Which is the correct sentence and use of the of the word spend/spent

Tags: word-usage, active-vs-passive

> 1. $13,000 - average domestic spent by Kuwaiti families per month.
> 2. $13,000 - average domestic spend by Kuwaiti families per month.

Answer (score 2):

*Spend* as a noun means *amount of money spent*, so (2) is correct. *Domestic spend* is economists' jargon for *household expenditure.*

(1) would need to be changed to something like *average amount spent on domestic purposes*.